# How to compute intersection points between segments, and list their associated segments in CGAL 5.6?

Tags: c++, geometry, cgal

I am trying to use CGAL to compute the unique intersection points between a set of segments in 2D. I also want to obtain the list of segments that contribute to each intersection point. It seems that this was a built-in feature in CGAL 3.1 but can't find it in 5.6.

[This](https://doc.cgal.org/Manual/3.1/doc_html/cgal_manual/Sweep_line_2_ref/Class_Sweep_line_2.html) old documentation page appears to describe a deprecated class that allows exactly what I want, but I am not sure what the equivalent feature is in the later versions of CGAL.

The CGAL documentation has an example to compute intersection points [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_sweep_2/index.html) but it does not get the list of segments that contribute to each intersection point.

How can I do this using a recent version of CGAL (version 5.6 in my case)?

Comment: The same functions are available [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_sweep_2/group__PkgSurfaceSweep2Ref.html). The difference is that instead of being class functions they are free functions.

Comment: @sloriot it doesn't seem like any of those functions return the list of associated curves that contribute to each intersection point?

I am not really familiar  with 'traits' in CGAL; are you implying that the information is contained inside that?

Comment: You are actually right that the equivalent to `get_intersecting_curves()` seems lost. I'll ask the authors